# problem with imported package when running EXE created with pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created a Python package called ldm.xliff comprising everything shown here:

[image: ldm.xliff package]

The two Python files each contain two Classes.

I now have a Python script in which I import one of these Classes as follows:

[image: Class import]

This works fine.

The problem I have is that when I compile my scripts into an EXE using pyinstaller, I receive the following error message when I run the EXE.

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "memoq_edit_distance\pre_tran.py", line 123, in <module>
  File "memoq_edit_distance\pre_tran.py", line 91, in logic
  File "ldm\xliff\xliff.py", line 219, in __init__
  File "ldm\xliff\xliff.py", line 31, in __init__
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\LUTZMO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI170282\\ldm\\xliff\\data\\namespaces\\xliff.json'
[8980] Failed to execute script 'pre_tran' due to unhandled exception!*
```

I do not understand why a search is being performed in this path. The xliff.json mentioned in the error message is part of my imported ldm.xliff package.

Not sure whether I have provided enough information here, but if someone has an idea/suggestion I'd be grateful to hear from them.

Comment: If `xliff.json` is a json file then it is not part of your package.  just like when you create a package for pypi you need to indicate to build backend if and where you have extra data files to include, the same is true for pyinstaller.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I have tried adding the file with the option —add-data <SRC;DEST as well as by adding the paths to the spec file, but I still get the same error message. Don’t know what I’m doing wrong.